# Finding the difference between two tables based on a common key (Microsoft SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables that share a common key and a few different columns. The common key is `CampaignID`. One of the tables has slightly more `CampaignID`'s than the other one and I would like to find out the difference between those two tables. Currently, I am using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `CTE` to merge these two tables first, then by inspecting `NULL` columns in the `CTE` result set derived in the earlier step to count the difference in `CampaignID` column. For instance,

```
WITH CTE_Results
     AS (SELECT t1.CampaignID AS cd_CampaignID,
                t2.CampaignID AS cod_CampaignID,
                t1.NAME,
                t2.Vendor
         FROM   CampaignDetails AS t1
                LEFT OUTER JOIN CampaignOnlineDetails AS t2
                             ON t1.CampaignID = t2.CampaignID)

-- Now that I have CTE result, I'll use another SELECT to find the difference
SELECT cd_CampaignID, cod_CampaignID
FROM CTE_Results
WHERE cod_CampaignID is NULL
```

But this seems inefficient to me. Is there a more efficient/faster way to compare the difference in a specific column between two tables in Microsoft SQL Server? Thank you for your answers!

NOTE: I'm new to Microsoft SQL Server and SQL in general.

Comment: The cte is not needed here but isn't going to affect performance. You could just add the where clause "where t.cod_CampaingID IS NULL" to your main query. But it isn't going to make any different to the execution plan. If you only want the two campaignID columns you should exclude them from your inner query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one table has more than the other then how bout:

```
SELECT C1.* FROM CAMPAIGN_WITH_MORE_DATA AS C1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CAMPAIGN_WITH_LESS_DATA AS C2
                                WHERE C2.CAMPAIGN_ID = C1.CAMPAIGN_ID)
```

If either may have one campaign or not then `UNION` this:

```
SELECT C1.Name AS [Col1],
  C1.CAMPAIGN_ID,
  'More Campaigns' AS [Source]
FROM CAMPAIGN_WITH_MORE_DATA AS C1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CAMPAIGN_WITH_LESS_DATA AS C2
                 WHERE C2.CAMPAIGN_ID = C1.CAMPAIGN_ID)
UNION ALL
SELECT C2.Vendor AS [Col1],
  C2.CAMPAIGN_ID,
  'Less Campaigns' AS [Source]
FROM CAMPAIGN_WITH_LESS_DATA AS C2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CAMPAIGN_WITH_MORE_DATA AS C1
                 WHERE C1.CAMPAIGN_ID = C2.CAMPAIGN_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exists is likely more efficient than a left join. This'll work too:

```
SELECT CampaignID FROM CampaignDetails
EXCEPT
SELECT CampaignID FROM CampaignOnlineDetails
```

Just reverse order to check the other way round.

Comment: the solution you suggested also works, but I accepted McKeown's answer because he submitted first and his also works. Thank you. :)